# Intermittent 401 Unauthorized Error with AWS Amplify and Expo in React Native App

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

I'm developing a React Native app using Expo and AWS Amplify. I've encountered an intermittent issue where I receive the following error: Error fetching user data: {"data": {}, "errors": [[GraphQLError: Request failed with status code 401]]}. This error seems to occur even though I haven't made any changes to the Amplify backend.

To provide some context, I have included aws-exports.js in .gitignore, which I suspect might be causing the issue during eas build, as the file might not be properly loaded. To address this, I added "eas-build-pre-install": "echo $AWS_EXPORTS_JSON_BASE64 | base64 -d > ./src/aws-exports.js" to my package.json and commented out # aws-exports.js in .easignore. Despite these measures, the error still occurs occasionally.

I find myself needing to run amplify push api every time to resolve this, but I'm looking for a more permanent solution. Could the issue be related to the aws-exports.js file not being read during the build process, or is there something else I'm missing?

- schema.graphql

```
  @model
  @auth(rules: [
    { allow: public, operations: [read] },
    { allow: owner, provider: userPools },
    { allow: private, provider: userPools, operations: [read, update] }
  ])
```

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Start the update process:

```
amplify update api
```

After running the command, you will be prompted with the following questions:

For "Please select from one of the below mentioned services," choose "GraphQL."

For "Select from the options below," select "Update auth settings."

For "Choose the default authorization type for the API," select "API key."

For "Enter a description for the API key," provide a description of your API key.

For "After how many days from now the API key should expire (1-365)," enter the new expiration date within the range of 1 to 365 days.

If you do not need to configure additional auth types:

For "Configure additional auth types?" select "No."
Apply the changes:

```
amplify push
```

These steps will allow you to change the expiration date of the AppSync API key used in AWS Amplify.